# Unable to read data from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Recently i am trying working on an IOS app and had just started using the newly revamp firebase for all the backend stuff. I was following the default IOS tutorial below

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-objc/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

for firebase and trying to integrate a portion of the code in the tutorial into my IOS app project.

Basically, I am trying to read data from firebase and display it on my IOS app, however, i am unable to get it to work and I can't figure out why.

With the help of the tutorial, I had completed the below needed steps
1) Added GoogleService-Info.plist file
2) Input the correct bundle ID
3) Installed all the Firebase related pods
4) Added the rules to "read" and "write" the data

Below is an image of my firebase database:

[image]

Below is an image of my function to read data from firebase:

[image]

I do not encounter any major error when running the app. I can compile the code smoothly. However, I just can't get the code to print out the data in the Xcode console using NSLog.

Any kind advise? -- solved, look at the commends below for answer

Comment: May be I have found the error, may be this can be the reason.

While in Code you mentioned that `hotel_bookings`
and in Firebase Console there is `hotel bookings`

Comment: Thanks! it works!! :)

Comment: So +1 to increase my comment please. Thanks :)

Comment: I need to remove _dataRef = [_ref child:@"data];

Comment: ha, how may i +1 to increase your comment? I am trying to figure this out. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting data because you are querying for a key `hotel_bookings` while on the firebase side you have key `hotel bookings`,

You can do either one thing , convert your key to `hotel_bookings` in your `FireBase Database` and its a good thing not have spaces in your keys.

See if this helps..

Comment: yes it works! thanks alot! I guess sometimes when a person is too fixated in debugging, he will missed the obvious!

Comment: :D yes this happens with everyone , and yes you should try and not keep space in yours keys if possible, just a suggestion though :)

Comment: yes, good point! :)